# Google Sheets: Find and Replace different text values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm continually adding new rows to Google Sheets. I need 2 scripts (not formulas!) to find and replace text values in 2 different columns.

**Script 1:**
In Column D, I have multiple rows that contain 1 of 2 values:

1. Jones
2. JD-Market

I need ALL rows in Column D to read: JD-Market

**Script 2:**
In Column E, I have multiple rows that contain URLs. I need to find and replace certain text within those URLs with other text.

Sample URL: http://www.sample.com/test/boat-water/2468

I want to replace only "boat-water" with "car-road"

New URL: http://www.sample.com/test/car-road/2468

I can't use formulas for these changes. I need to use scripts.

Thanks for your help! Much appreciated!

Comment: Do your columns have headers? Or are they just columns a,b,c,d,e...etc?

Answer (score 1):

Would you please elaborate more about your requirement ?

As my understanding, you want to replace column E url only when parallel column D contain 'JD-Market'.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
for(var i =1; i<=lastrow; i++){
  //var tempval = sheet.getRange("D"+i).getValue();
  //if(tempval == 'JD-Market'){
    var oldurl = sheet.getRange("E"+i).getValue();
    var newurl = oldurl.replace("boat-water", "car-road");
    sheet.getRange("E"+i).setValue(newurl);
  //}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @YNK. But the 2 scripts I need are "independent" of one another. I need them to run simultaneously to address different parts of my sheet. Script 1 will address data in Column D. Script 2 will address data in Column E.

Comment: For that you can create two different function within a single script and run each using button click or event object(Open, Change, Edit) base as required.

Comment: Thanks @YNK. Can you help me write that script? The script you listed above makes the 2nd function (change URL) dependent on the 1st value = JD-Market. But both functions are independent of each other. I want to change URL in Column E regardless of what happens in Column D.

Comment: Sure... For that, we just need to remove condition only.. please recheck my answer, i have edit the code as your requirement...

Comment: '@YNK... OK, Column E function is working properly. But Column D function is not. I'm no expert, but I don't think you included the original value ("Jones") that I want changed to ("JD-Market"). You've been putting a lot of time into this :). Is it possible for you to edit the script again? Perhaps it might be best to separate these scripts into 2 separate stand-alone functions. Thanks!

Comment: @NTC why not sure... But let me confirm about 1st script function again, here you want to replace all 'Jones' with 'JD-Market', my i right ? if not, then would you please elaborate 1st task again ?

Comment: I think I jury-rigged it :). I separated the script above in half... first half... 'var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
for(var i =1; i<=lastrow; i++){
    var oldurl = sheet.getRange("D"+i).getValue();
    var newurl = oldurl.replace("Jones", "JD-Market");
    sheet.getRange("D"+i).setValue(newurl);
  //}
}' ...

Comment: 2nd half... 'var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
for(var i =1; i<=lastrow; i++){
    var oldurl = sheet.getRange("E"+i).getValue();
    var newurl = oldurl.replace("boat-water", "car-road");
    sheet.getRange("E"+i).setValue(newurl);
  //}
}'

Comment: it works! of course, Column D is NOT a URL. can i change the words 'old url' and 'new url' for the Column D function? Thank you!